# How to prove that if $68$ numbers are selected from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 100\}$, then at least three must be consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I need to prove this and find a group without three consecutive numbers. I've tried to come with a solution by  pigeonhole principle, but I think I am not close to that. I having a hard time to provide a combinatorial solution and declaring what is the pigeonholes and what is the pigeon number. Help please.

> Prove that each subgroup of size $68$ of $\{100, \ldots, 2, 1\}$ has three consecutive numbers. Find a subgroup of size $67$ that does not have three consecutive numbers.

Comment: Well, the obvious collection to try is $\{1,2,4,5,7,8,\cdots,98,100\}$, no?

Comment: Hint for the second part: how many multiples of three do you have between 1 and 100?

Comment: @lulu was 10s faster than me. :)

Comment: lol 10 s XD       ok I understand how to find a grop without three consecutive numbers. .. but how I Prove that each subgroup of size 68 {100,… 2,, 1} has three consecutive numbers.

Comment: Every group  $(1,2,3),(4,5,6),..........(97,98,99)$ must be missing at least one term.  So you can only have at most $2$ of each of those $33$ groups.  So you can only have at most $99-33=66$ of the numbers between $1$ and $99$.  And if you also have $100$ you can only have at most $67$ numbers.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the explanation, sorry for the stupidity, if you can explain again, and how I officially write it down. I mean to the prove with the 68 that to all sub group size68 have 3 consectuve numbers

Comment: I'm not sure I can make it simpler.  If you want to pick $K$ numbers without 3 consecutive integers you can only pick at most $2$ out of each of the triplets $(1,2,3)(4,5,6),(7,8,9).... (97,98,99)$.  That means you can only pick at most $66$ out of $1,2,3,...,99$.  That means you can only pick at most $67$ out of $1,2,3,...,100$.  If you pick $68 > 67$ you must pick $3$ out of at least one of those triplets.  And if you pick $3$ out of one of those triplet you picked three consecutive numbers.

Comment: Okay.... You have $34$ holes Hole 1: (1,2,3) Hole 2: (4,5,6)..... Hole 33: (97,98,99) and Hole 34: (100).  You have $68$ pigeons.  That is an average of $2$ pigeons per hole.  If one of the holes has fewer pigeons than average, than at least one of the holes will have more pigeons than average.  But hole 34: (100) has at most $1$ pigeon.  That's below average.  So at least one hole has more than $2$ pigeons.  That's at least $3$ pigeons.  But if a hole has $3$ pigeons then that hole consists of three consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily construct sets of $67$ elements having no $3$ consecutive numbers. Now, consider the following,
$$(1,2,3)$$
$$(4,5,6)$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$(97,98,99)$$
Suppose you have a set of $68$ elements such that no $3$ elements are consecutive. Remaining elements are $32$ and above written are $33$ triplets. Hence, by **pigeonhole principle**, there must be a triplet no element of which is remaining. Hence, there must be $3$ consecutive numbers in this set. Contradiction !

Hope it helps:)

Comment: wait your said that you have 68 elements that no 3 elements are consecutive and the left  elements are 32 numbers. ok so how u get from the  pigeonhole principle to Contradiction . what the holes and what the pigeons

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty obvious that the best you can do to get as many numbers without getting three consecutive numbers is to pick $1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,$ etc. This ends with $97,98,100$, which gives a total of $67$ numbers. You could also end with $97,99,100$, and in fact you can ‘shift’ numbers in quite a few ways, so there are many solutions with $67$ numbers

Now, why exactly can't you add one more number and get to $68$? Well, consider that the sequence as indicated has exactly $2$ numbers out of every consecutive $3$ ... So, that's really the maximum you can get.

Comment: ok I understand how to find a grop without three consecutive numbers. .. but how I Prove that each subgroup of size 68 {100,… 2,, 1} has three consecutive numbers.

Comment: "but it also seems obvious you can’t squeeze in an extra number"  I'm not sure that follows.  That assumes $1,2,4,5, etc. $ or $1,3,4,6,7 etc$ are the only two ways to get $67$ shoved in or that it's so efficient you can't shuffle and get one more it. You need a pigeon hole argument I think.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the the $33$ groups $A_k=(3k-2, 3k -1, 3k)$ for $k= 1.....33$. You can only pick at most $2$ from each $A_k$.  If you pick all $3$ from $A_k$ then the numbers in $A_k$ are three consecutive numbers.

So you can only pick at most $2*33=66$ numbers out of the numbers between $1$ and $99$.  If you pick $100$ you can pick at most the number $100$ and $66$ others for $67$ maximum numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose at most 2 out of every three consecutive numbers to avoid it. But,that only chooses 66 numbers. Add in one of the end points (in the easiest case 100). That makes 67. okay. That means in every set of three, we have 2, and a single set of 1. If we try adding one more to our 67, we hit that we would have to get one from the numbers not chosen in the 33 sets of 3 before. This will end up using up all of at least one of the sets of 3. but those 3 are 3 consecutive numbers. Contradiction.